# ajax call simple issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This simple code and I needs your help..
I click this button(editsubmit) and it goes to another page called trailnew.php.. I want to check if the result is success or not...

I put this in trailnew.php

```
    <?php
    $e=isset($_POST['editsubmit']) && $_POST['editsubmit'];
    if($e)
    {
        echo "inserted";
    }
    ?>
```

And the script..

```
<script>
    $("#editsubmit").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#form2").submit()
    });

    $("#form2").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            plnoedit:"required",
            pldtedit:"required",
            noboxedit:"required",
            glidedit:"required",
        },
        messages: {
            plnoedit: "Please select a pack list id..",
            pldtedit: "Please select a item id id..",
            noboxedit: "Please select a quantity id..",
            glidedit: "Please select a value id..",
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "trailnew.php",
                data: $('#form2').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
      });
</script>
```

The first page(trailnew.php)

```
<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>


 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

 <script>


  $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#form1").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {
    
    plid:"required",
       },
   messages: {
    
    plid: "Please select a pack name id..",
    },
    
    submitHandler: function(form) {
 
    $.ajax
   ({
  
type: "POST",
url: "aanew.php",
data: $('#form1').serialize(),
cache: false,

success: function(response) {
    $('#result1').html(response); 
            
        }
        });
        }
  
  });

  </script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="result3"></div>
Packing List
</br>
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="" method="post">
<?php   

echo '<select  name="plid" id="plid">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select the Pack Name--</option>';
$tempholder = array();
$sql="SELECT CONCAT( p.pl_no,  '_', DATE_FORMAT( p.pl_dt,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) ,  '_', g.acname ) AS plname, g.gl_id,p.pl_no,p.pl_dt,p.no_box,p.pl_id,g.acname FROM packlist p, glmast g WHERE g.gl_id = p.gl_id ORDER BY pl_dt DESC , pl_no DESC LIMIT 30";


$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$nr = mysql_num_rows($query);
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++){
$r = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if (!in_array($r['plname'], $tempholder)){
$tempholder[$i] = $r['plname'];
echo "<option value='$r[pl_id]'>".$r["plname"]."</option>";
}
}

echo '</select>';

?><br/>

<input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" value="Delete"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="edit" id="edit" value="Edit"/><br/>
</form>


<form>
<input type="button" name="new" id="new" class="new" value="New" /><br/>
</form>

<?php
$e=isset($_POST['editsubmit']) && $_POST['editsubmit'];
if($e)
{
echo "inserted!";
}
?>

<div id="result1"></div>  

</body>

</html>
```

The second page(aanew.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connect.php');
?>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#editsubmit").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     $("#form2").submit()
});
 $("#form2").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {

    plnoedit:"required",
    pldtedit:"required",
    noboxedit:"required",
    glidedit:"required",


       },
   messages: {

    plnoedit: "Please select a pack list id..",
    pldtedit: "Please select a item id id..",
    noboxedit: "Please select a quantity id..",
    glidedit: "Please select a value id..",

        },

         submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.ajax
   ({


type: "POST",
url: "trailnew.php",
data: $('#form2').serialize(),
cache: false,
success: function(data)
        {
            window.alert(data);
        }


        });
        return false;
        }



  });


</script>
<script>

 $("#form3").validate({
         debug: false,
   rules: {

    plnodelete:"required",
    pldtdelete:"required",
    noboxdelete:"required",
    gliddelete:"required",


       },
   messages: {

    plnodelete: "Please select a pack list id..",
    pldtdelete: "Please select a item id id..",
    noboxdelete: "Please select a quantity id..",
    gliddelete: "Please select a value id..",

        },

         submitHandler: function(form) {

    $.ajax
   ({


type: "POST",
url: "trailnew.php",
data: $('#form3').serialize(),
cache: false,
success: function() {
    alert('Deleted!'); 

        }


        });
        return false;
        }



  });

</script>
</head>

        <body>
        <div id="#result1"></div>
        <?php

    $e=isset($_POST['plid']) && $_POST['plid'];
    $f=isset($_POST['edit']) && $_POST['edit'];
    if($e&&$f)
    {


    $id=$_POST['plid'];
    $query5=mysql_query("SELECT g.gl_id, p.pl_no, p.pl_dt, p.no_box, p.pl_id,g.acname
        FROM packlist p, glmast g
        WHERE g.gl_id = p.gl_id
        AND p.pl_id ='".$id."'
        LIMIT 0 , 30") or die(mysql_error());

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query5);
    $pl_no=$row['pl_no'];
    $pl_dt=$row['pl_dt'];
    $no_box=$row['no_box'];
    $acname=$row['acname'];



    ?>
        <form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="">
        <P>
            <LABEL for="plnoedit">PackList No 
                      <INPUT type="text" id="plnoedit" name="plnoedit" value= <?php echo $pl_no; ?> /></LABEL><BR><BR>
                      <input type="hidden" name="myFormsName" value="form5id" id="myFormsName">
                      <input type="hidden" name="pdidedit" value=<?php echo $id; ?> id="pdidedit">
            <LABEL for="pldtedit">Date 
                      <INPUT type="text" id="pldtedit" name="pldtedit" value= <?php echo $pl_dt; ?> /></LABEL><BR><BR>

            <LABEL for="noboxedit">Box No
                      <INPUT type="text" id="noboxedit" name="noboxedit" value= <?php echo $no_box; ?> /></LABEL><BR><BR>
            <LABEL for="glidedit">Party Name
                      <INPUT type="text" id="glidedit" name="glidedit" value= <?php echo $acname; ?> /></LABEL><BR><BR>

            <INPUT type="button" id="editsubmit" name="editsubmit" value="Submit"> <INPUT type="reset">
            </P> 

        </form>
        <?php

              }

             ?>


        </body>
        </html>
```

The code goes to the trainnew.php I guess, But the alert has all the html loaded into it(The entire new fresh trainnew.php page).. Any suggestions,please?

From Trainnew.php

I use a Edit submit button to get a form from aanew.php(by ajax)

Now I validate this new form in trailnew.php(with validation code in trailnew.php)

Now the problem is that the success ajax call from this form on submit handler, gives me

the entire new page of trailnew.php..What is that I am doing wrong??

I am trying to figure this from yesterday.... I missing something important here I guess.. Or ajax parts.. Any help highly appreciated!! Thanks a lot in advance..

Comment: Your codes is too much for debugging!

Comment: @Mojtaba I have deleted some... The alert response success call alers entire HTML page... I just want the php code to be there..What is that I amdoing wrong..Thanks

Comment: You want to get alert `inserted` only?

Comment: @Mojtaba I want to check if the form is processed or not...

Comment: How we must know the form is processed or not? You send an ajax request to `trailnew.php` and it process the form. You mean that we check your PHP code? Or something else?

Comment: @Mojtaba No... Ok..I have posted the code now..That is the entire code I am using.. So when the editsubmit button is pressed, I want to get some data from the trailnew.php(To know It went through if block).. This is what I want to achieve..May be this is simple, I am complicating it..Any suggestions please..Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29788/discussion-between-user2234992-and-mojtaba)

Answer (score 0):

```
 success: function() {
    alert('Success');  
  }
```

Why are you alerting the data when u don't need it !

Comment: To check if the particular form goes into manipulation... I want to check if the form gets processed or not?? SO.. But I get the entire html page as alert.. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

You must stop the trailnew.php page to execute completly

Your code

```
<?php
$e=isset($_POST['editsubmit']) && $_POST['editsubmit'];
if($e)
{
    echo "inserted";
}
?>
```

You must do this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['editsubmit']) && $_POST['editsubmit'])
{
    die('inserted'); // this stop the page right here
}
?>
```